# Induction proof with summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

For this question, I'm stuck on the inductive step for this proof. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks

$\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.Use this result to prove that if m and n are any positive integers and m is odd, then $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (n+k) $ is divisible by m.  Does the conclusion hold if m is even?  Justify your answer

Base Case:
m = 3, n = 0

$\frac{3}{(0+1+2)}$

$\frac{3}{3}$

Let r be an odd integer such that m = 2r+1

Inductive Step:

2r+1|$\sum_{i=0}^{2r} (n+k) $ -> 2r+2|$\sum_{i=0}^{2r} (n+k) $

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What is $k$ in $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (n+k) $? As it's current stated, the result would just be $m(n+k)$. However, I assume you meant either $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (n+k) $ or $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (n+i) $. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that
you want to show that
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (n+k)
$
is divisible by $m$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
s(m, n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (n+k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} n+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} k\\
&=mn+\dfrac{(m-1)m}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

If $m$ is odd then
$m=2j+1$
for some integer $j$
so

$\begin{array}\\
s(m, n)
&=mn+\dfrac{(2j+1-1)m}{2}\\
&=mn+\dfrac{(2j)m}{2}\\
&=mn+jm\\
&=m(n+j)\\
\end{array}
$

is divisible by $m$.

Comment: Wait why didn't you sub m = 2j+1 into mn?

Comment: It wasn't needed. Only needed to show that m+1 was even. The other term was already divisible by m.